# Firebase hosting with continously growing number of audio files

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-hosting

I am developing a mobile app with firebase 3, ionic2 and Angular2.
We will continuously create new audio files that will be offered to all our subscribed users, i.e. the audio files are not user specific. The audio files are offered in modules and in succession. In other words, a subscribed user will only be able to listen to the next file in a module when all previous files in that module have been listened to.

Firebase hosting doesn't seem to work for this purpose as it is my understanding that whenever we'd add a new audio we would have to upload the entire site with all previous and new audio files as content. That would be incredibly tedious and not a workable solution.
Am I wrong about this assumption? I haven't seen any incremental upload for hosting or ftp access to it.

As an alternative I am now considering firebase storage to host our audio files. However, in that case I am not sure how to secure the storage. Since my api key must be public in the source (js or html file) it seems to me that every subscribed user with a bit of js knowledge can gain access to the folders that host our audio files and then just download them.

In the case of hosting them I would be able to hash the file names and store them in the database and thereby control access to them.
However, using the storage option that doesn't seem possible since people could just download all files in a folder and thereby download the entire module.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: If you want to secure access to file in Firebase Storage based on user credentials, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/

Answer (score 0):

It all depends upon how you are storing these audio files in Firebase. Avoid storing files in a base64 format and leverage use of [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/).

Would highly recommend use of either-

1. Firebase Storage to incrementally store audio files and provide
   users with an uninterrupted stream.
2. Upload images to s3 and incrementally save the Hash in firebase with the use of arrays-

   var messages = $FirebaseArray(ref);

   // add a new record to the list
   messages.$add({
     user: "physicsmarie",
     text: "Hello world"
   });

   // remove an item from the list
   messages.$remove(someRecordKey);

   // change a message and save it
   var item = messages.$getRecord(someRecordKey);
   item.user = "alanisawesome";
   messages.$save(item).then(function() {
     // data has been saved to our database
   });

Comment: 1. Yes, as I said in my Op that's what I am considering. However, my question is how to secure them. 2. I don't see what hosting images in S3 has to do with the issue at hand.